# C program that counts the number of characters in the comments

Tags: c, arrays, string

Hello i am making a C program that counts the number of characters in the comments of a source file witout adding '/*' , '*/'  characters in the counting. My code only seems to count only the comments before the int main() function. Can someone offer me some guidence on how to resolve this issue ?

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#endif 

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

//hi/
int main()
{
    //hi/
    char filename[199];
    char c[1000];//hi/
    FILE *filep;
    int comments = 0;
    gets(filename);


    if (!(filep = fopen(filename, "r")))  
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error! File %s not found\n", filename);
        return;
    }

    while (fgets(c, sizeof(c), filep) != 0)
    {
        int len = strlen(c);
        for (int i = 0; i <= len; i++)
        {
                if (c[i] == '/' && c[i] == '/')
                {
                    comments += (strlen(c) - 2);
                    break;
                }
                if (c[i] == '/' && c[i] == '*')
                    comments += (strlen(c) - 2);
                break;

        }   
    }

    fclose(filep);

    printf("%s: Number of characters in comments: %d\n", filename,comments);
_getche();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (c[i] == '/' && c[i] == '/')` and `(c[i] == '/' && c[i] == '*')`. why? the second one should be `c[i+1]`

Comment: `strlen(c) - 2` should be `strlen(c) - 2 - i`. And in the case of `/*` you'll need to search for the corresponding `*/` because there can be code after it in the same line.

Comment: How robust does this code need to be? For example, should it be able to handle `//` inside strings?

Comment: Challenge with this approach: 1) source code `char *s = "//";` as this code will consider the string literal as a comment. 2) This assumes comments that begin with `"/*"` run to the end of the line.  3) It does not detect `"/*"` comments that run multiple lines 4) Could go on with a number of others, but it is challenging to do this right. It not a trivial task.

Comment: Roughly speaking the  program needs to keep track of when it is in a `/*` comment, `//` comment, `""` string, `''` char literal, `#` preprocessor statement or normal code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to compare the two characters. Make the condition as follows.

```
if (c[i] == '/' && c[i+1] == '/')

if (c[i] == '/' && c[i+1] == '*')
```

from this you can check the current character and the next character.

Then in for loop why the break statement. Are you expecting the lop have to run for one time. Remove the `break;` Because the comment is place anywhere in the line. If you wnat to check only one time don't remove the `break;`,then make the for loop as

`for (int i = 0; i < len-1 ; i++)`

Comment: This is not enough! It is just one out of several problems.

Comment: you missed the major problem. Hint: `/*...*/` is usually used in multiline comments. don't you want to check for the ending match?

Comment: Yes i do want to check for an ending match.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is thanks to @Karthikeyan.R.S
The code is working. Added some random comments to test it out.

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#endif 

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

/*hi*/
int main()
{
    char filename[199];
    char c[1000];
    FILE *filep;
    int comments = 0;
    gets(filename); 
    /*hi*/
    /*hi*/
    /*hi*/

    if (!(filep = fopen(filename, "r")))  
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error! File %s not found\n", filename);
        return;
    }
    //hi/


    while (fgets(c, sizeof(c), filep) != 0)
    {
        int len = strlen(c);
        for (int i = 0; i < len - 1; i++)
        {
                if (c[i] == '/' && c[i+1] == '/')

                {
                    comments += (strlen(c)-3-i );

                }
                if (c[i] == '/' && c[i + 1] == '*')
                    comments += (strlen(c) - 5 - i);


        }   
    }

    fclose(filep);
    /*hi*/
    printf("%s: Number of characters in comments: %d\n", filename,comments);
_getche();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't you get any warnings when compiling this?